# How to find number of rows inserted in table on particular date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fget the count of rows inserted in table on given date. but I dont have a schema which supports me to do so.

Here is my database schema

```
 Field                   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Name                   | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Degree                 | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Contact no             | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Address                | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

can anyone help me to get the results.

I want to finds all the records which were inserted on 19/09/2014 or likewise.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add date column in your table

Comment: what's your rdbms? mysql or mssql?

Comment: This will more like help me in future. but what can I do to get the result from current schema ?

Answer (score 1):

Any MySQL table will not have an internal timestamp of record insertion. Explicitly defining a column in the schema which stored the inserted timestamp in a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME field would have allowed you to query based on that timestamp, which I am afraid is impossible in this case.

If you have the [general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) of mysql enabled, you can try reconstructing the data along with the timestamp from there.

Comment: while googling for the same I came across a query which might be helpful but genrated wrong results for me. so can u figure out whats the problem with this query.   SELECT DATE(added) as date, COUNT(*) FROM bookings WHERE added = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY date

Comment: This query is for a different table, a different schema. I am guessing that "added" is the timestamp field here, which you do not have in your table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a datetime column (f.e. CreatedDate) in order to do this.